# Pi-type over a list in dependent type theory

Tags: type-theory, dependent-type, agda

In a formalization I need to create an inductive type which has a term for each element in a list, something like this (I'll use Agda in the following, but everything here is standard dependent type theory):

```
data DataType : Type where
  inj : (xs : List A) → (x : {! xs !}) → DataType
```

Of course, we cannot have a Pi type over `x : xs` in the middle since `xs` is a *term* and not a type, so we cannot quantify over it.

We can use singletons to get an n-tuple from a list as follows:

```
Singleton : (x : A) → Type
Singleton x = Σ[ y ∈ A ] (y ≡ x)

list→type : List A → Type
list→type [] = ⊥
list→type (x ∷ []) = Singleton x
list→type (x ∷ y ∷ xs) = Singleton x × list→type (y ∷ xs)
```

That way a list `1 ∷ 2 ∷ 3 ∷ []` is turned into the tuple `(s1, s2, s3)`, from which can recover the numbers in the list. However, this tuple is still just one term, so we will only have a single `inj (s1, s2, s3)` in our data type above when using `list→type xs` in the Pi type above.

How can we get a different inhabitant in `DataType` for each element of the list? Is there a standard way to deal with that? Or do I fundamentally misunderstand something? It's of course a bit awkward to mix a data structure understanding of "collection" with the basic doctrine of regarding types as collections (with explicit term constructors), but it still should be possible to reconcile both understandings I hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an auxiliary predicate `x ∈ ℓ` whose elements are all the positions in `ℓ` at which `x` appears. With that in hand, you can do it as follows:

```
data List (A : Set) : Set where
  [] : List A
  _::_ : A → List A → List A

infixr 5 _::_
infix 4 _∈_

data _∈_ {A} (x : A) : List A → Set where
  ∈-head : ∀ {ℓ} → x ∈ x :: ℓ
  ∈-tail : ∀ {y} {ℓ} → x ∈ ℓ → x ∈ y :: ℓ

data DataType (A : Set) : Set where
  inj : (xs : List A) → ∀ x → x ∈ xs → DataType A

data Five : Set where
  one two three four five : Five

mylist = two :: three :: two :: five :: []

demo : DataType Five
demo = inj mylist two ∈-head

demo' : DataType Five
demo' = inj mylist two (∈-tail (∈-tail ∈-head))
```

Is that what you had in mind? If not, you should explicitly state how many elements you expect `DataType A ℓ` to have. As many as there are elements of `ℓ`?

Comment: Thank you, the simple definition of ∈ is really all I needed to clear up my confusion. I also found this paper helpful, which establishes some connections between lists and finite sets: http://firsov.ee/finset/finset.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You asked several questions.

You asked about a type indexed by a list, so you can do this.

```
data DataType (A : Type) (F : A -> Type) : List A -> Type where
  empty : DataType A F []
  _bla_ : forall {xs} {x} -> DataType A F xs -> F x -> DataType A F (x ∷ xs)
```

Where `F` is a type family that is indexed by the elements of the list.

Apart from that, you mentioned tuples. Probably you want a sized vector (`Data.Vec` in stdlib) for tuples. For instance, `Vec Nat 3` is such a type that `1 ∷ 2 ∷ []` and `1 ∷ 2 ∷ 3 ∷ 4 ∷ []` are both invalid instances, only `1 ∷ 2 ∷ 3 ∷ []` is.

Comment: This solution is probably what the OP wanted, mine is probably is not.

Comment: My attempted solution with iterated Sigma-types was gaslighting and due to a confusion on my side, I was really only wondering about how to express membership in a list. Hence I chose Andrej's answer, but thanks for your response ice1000!